# Find a basis for the kernel of $u \otimes v$ and matrix $u \otimes v$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Hello everyone I have the two following questions left without any correction and I'm having a hard time resolving it if anyone could help me  it would be a lot appreciated.

Let $E,F,G,H$ vector space with finite dimension. We have $u \in \mathcal L(E,G)$ and $v \in \mathcal L(F,H)$ , (where $\mathcal L(F,H)$ is the linear mapping $F \rightarrow H$).
We define $e_1 , ... , e_n $ as a basis for $E$ , $f_1 , ... , f_p$ a basis for $F$

We suppose that the basis of their kernel are respectively :  $e_1 , ... e_k$ and $f_1 , ... , f_l$ .

> 1. Find the basis of the kernel for :  $u \otimes v$ ?

Let $(a_{ij})$  the matrix of $u$ in the basis $e_j$ and $g_i$  , Let $(b_{kl})$ the matrix of $v$ in the basis $f_l$ and $h_k$

> 2. Find the matrix of $u\otimes v$ in the basis $e_j \otimes f_l$ and $g_i\otimes h_k$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello another question: if $E=G , F=H$ what can we say about the trace of $u \otimes v$ I found in my lecture a statement saying: that the trace of an endomorphism is the trace of the matrix in any basis is that right or useless?

Comment: To your second question that is indeed correct. Useless depends on what you're trying to do, but it doesn't seem relevant to this particular problem

Comment: @BenGrossmann alright thank you very much, I thought that using the matrix found in $2) $ and apply that statement could give us the trace ,  I thought it'll lead us somewhere

Comment: In fact, we have $\operatorname{tr}(u \otimes v) = \operatorname{tr}(u)\operatorname{tr}(v)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem: we will have $\ker(u \otimes v) = \ker(u) \otimes F + E \otimes \ker(g)$. One way to produce a basis is as follows:

Extend $e_1,\dots,e_k$ into a basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $E$, and extend $f_1,\dots,f_l$ into a basis $f_1,\dots,f_p$ of $F$. The set $\{e_i \otimes f_j : 1 \leq i \leq k \text{ or } 1 \leq j \leq l\}$ is a basis for $\ker(u \otimes v)$.

For the second problem: keep in mind that the order of the basis is important. Suppose that we order $\{e_j \otimes f_l\}$ so that the tuples $(j,l)$ are taken in lexicographical order. Suppose that $\{g_i \otimes h_k\}$ is ordered in the same way. The matrix of $u \otimes v$ relative to these basis will be the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) $A \otimes B$.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Grossmann , I have another little question . Can we say that if $u,v$ into , it implies  that $u\otimes v$ into also ?